# Trigonometric Equation involving powers

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sin^{2017}(x)+\sin^{2017}(7x)=2$$

I'm unable to solve this equation. Any hints for solving this type of problem?

Comment: Well, since $|\sin(x)|≤1$ you know a lot if you know that $\sin^n A +\sin^m B=2$.

Comment: $\sin(x)\le1$. Furthermore, if $\sin(x)=1$, then $\sin(nx)=-1$ for $n\equiv3\pmod4$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we have $sinx \leqslant 1$ for all x.

Thus,

$$ sin^{2017}(x) + sin^{2017}(7x) \leqslant 2$$

Consider that $sin(x) = 1$. We can use the comment made by @robjohn. Since $7 \equiv 3 (mod4)$, then $sin(7x) = -1$.

Hence,

$$ sin^{2017}(x) + sin^{2017}(7x) = 0$$

Thus, we have that $sin(x) < 1$. But in this case $sin^{2017}(x) < 1$. Therefore,

$$ sin^{2017}(x) + sin^{2017}(7x) < 2$$

we conclude that there are no solutions in $\mathbb{R}$.